# How to connect schemas with each other in mongooseJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Basically what I am trying to achieve is the following:
In my iOS application a QR-Code can be scanned to get the ID of a specific lounge and with that its JSON data (only ID and name for now) saved in MongoDB.

Every lounge is able (but doesn't have to) to add products to their lounge, so that in the end, after scanning the QR-Code, a customer is able to see which products are offered.

A product contains only a name and imageURL for now, but not a price, because the price can variate and be set by owners of a lounge. So a price of one and the same product can be different.

I would like to know, what the correct and best way is for implementing the schemas for that approach, so that I can easily fetch all products of a specific lounge, maybe based on its ID.

What I got so far:

lounge.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const loungeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Lounge', loungeSchema);

product.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    imageURL: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can use [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). You can achieve this by storing the products in separate collection and basically populate an array on the lounge schema using the _id for the lounge let me show you an example:

Your lounge schema would be something like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const loungeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true }
    products: [type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products' ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Lounge', loungeSchema);
```

And your product schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    imageURL: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

When saving creating a lounge just add the _id of the product to `products` array that apart of the lounge schema.
So basically you find the product and retrieve its _id.

To run a find query it would be something like this:

```
lounge.find({}).populate('products').exec();
```

products array will then have the related products for each lounge

Comment: Thank you! That's a very detailed answer! But how would a post method to the lounges document look like if I would like to directly add products to the productsArray when creating a new lounge? And can the productsArray be empty when posting a lounge without any product?

Comment: For consistency it would be best to add the lounge first then add the products after. So a separate method for each. If there are no products for a lounge the field will be null. See link for further details; mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found
Or even use the plain ref populate, saving the objectIds of the products the product array. ref would automatically no retrieve the appropriate documents https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs

Comment: Following situation: Me as kind of an admin, I would like to create the products first, stating what products are available in the App, so that I  tell the lounges something like: "We got the following products available in the App and you as a user when creating a lounge, can decide on which of these products you would like to offer for which price". I think with this background knowledge your answer is changing, am I wrong? :)

Comment: Okay i get you. I will upate my anwer using refs